# Merge expressions with a one-to-one join

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two text tables as below:
file1.txt

```
1 A a 
2 B b 
3 C c 
4 D d
```

file2.txt

```
A x i 
C z iii 
D w iiii 
B y ii
```

I want to have  
final.txt

```
1 A a x i 
2 B b y ii 
3 C c z iii 
4 D d w iiii
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ join  -12 -21 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2,2.3 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) > final.txt
1 A a x i
2 B b y ii
3 C c z iii
4 D d w iiii
```

- `join -12` = file 1 column 2 (ABCD), `-21` = file 2 column 1 (ABCD)
- `-o` = output, `2.3` = file 2, column 3.

```
$ paste -d' ' <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) | awk -F ' ' '{print $1, $2, $3, $5, $6}' > final.txt
1 A a x i
2 B b y ii
3 C c z iii
4 D d w iiii
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be scripted in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f1,open(sys.argv[2]) as f2:
    for f1_line in f1:
        f2_line = f2.readline()
        print(" ".join([f1_line.strip(),f2_line.strip()]))
```

Works as so:

```
$ ./merge.py file1.txt file2.txt 
1 A a A x i
2 B b C z iii
3 C c D w iiii
4 D d B y ii
```

You can create final.txt with shell redirection operator `./merge.py file1.txt file2.txt > final.txt`

---

If you have `sqlite3` installed and the two files are the same length you can script that in SQL since table field joins are exactly what SQL is designed to do:

```sql
sqlite3 <<EOF
.mode csv
.separator " "
CREATE TABLE tb1 (col1 INT,col2 TEXT,col3 TEXT);
CREATE TABLE tb2 (col1 TEXT,col2 TEXT,col3 TEXT);
.import file1.txt tb1
.import file2.txt tb2
SELECT * FROM tb1 JOIN tb2 on tb1.rowid=tb2.rowid;
EOF
```

Which works as so:

```
$ bash merge.sqlite
1 A a A x i
2 B b C z iii
3 C c D w iiii
4 D d B y ii
```

Note that original files shouldn't have trailing newlines, otherwise there will be errors thrown by SQLite.